# Powershell | Where-object Function Problem

Tags: powershell, escaping, match, get-childitem

I have got a problem with Where-object function in Powershell.

```
Get-ChildItem "$CurrentPath\TEMP"
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEFhB.png)

When I try to do a search on the name object, this is the result:

```
Get-ChildItem "$CurrentPath\TEMP" | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "[Erai-raws] B"}
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnYBX.png)

There must be some problem with the "[]" characters, if I do the same search with this I get a result:

```
Get-ChildItem "$CurrentPath\TEMP" | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "[Erai-raws] "}
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWD3L.png)

Do you have a solution to allow me to perform a search with the Name object knowing that my search variable is: [Erai-raws] Boku no Hero Academia 4th Season - 01 [720p] [Multiple Subtitle]

I have already tried with like, with match but as soon as I put "[] *", nothing more "match" ...

Thank you

Comment: You need to escape `[` and `]` when you use `-match`: `$_.Name -match [regex]::Escape('[Erai-raws] ')`

Comment: Check and try `[regex]::Escape("[Erai-raws] B")`

Answer (score 1):

Nice, works with regex escape :)

```
Get-ChildItem "$CurrentPath\TEMP" | Where-Object {$_.Name -match [regex]::Escape("[Erai-raws] Boku no Hero Academia 4th Season - 01 [720p][Multiple Subtitle]")}
```

thank you for your help and your responsiveness, subject lock :).